# Deploying production ember-cli app on openshift

Tags: ember.js, openshift, ember-cli

Can someone share step by step how to deploy and run a production ember-cli app on openshift?

I am not sure of the process and openshift cli steps to do this.

Locally I use ember serve but I'm not sure what to do when it runs in openshift.

Comment: Do you plan to run this on fastboot mode or static by running it behind nginx?

Comment: what do you recommend?

Comment: if SEO is important for you then it should run on fastboot mode, if not it can be configured behind a nginx.